# What is the hash algorithm used by Google's mod_pagespeed?

Tags: apache-http-server, hashing

Google's mod_pagespeed for Apache server produces the following url structure by appending an hash string:

```
...pagespeed.jc.bFZBaW2xkN.js
```

What is the hash algorithm used in this process?